# Find two functions such that $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,f{{\left( x \right)}^{g\left( x \right)}}=\pi $.

Tags: calculus

Is it in principle possible to define two functions $f\left( x \right)$, $g\left( x \right)$, such that $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,f\left( x \right)=\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,g\left( x \right)=0$ and $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,f{{\left( x \right)}^{g\left( x \right)}}=\pi $.
I tried  $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,f{{\left( x \right)}^{g\left( x \right)}}=\left[ {{0}^{0}} \right]={{e}^{\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,g\left( x \right)\log f\left( x \right)}}$, $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,g\left( x \right)\log f\left( x \right)=\log \pi $ since $\pi ={{e}^{\log \pi }}$. $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,g\left( x \right)\log f\left( x \right)=\left[ 0\infty  \right]=\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{f'\left( x \right){{\left( g\left( x \right) \right)}^{2}}}{g'\left( x \right)\left( -x \right)}=\log \pi $ using the L'Hopital's Rule. Unfortunately, I’m stuck right here. Perhaps I even went in the wrong direction with my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $g(x) \log f(x)$ to tend to $\log\pi$. To do this, make use of the fact that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (ax^2)}{x^2} = a$$ by setting $\log f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x) =-\sin (\log(\pi) x^2)$. The negative signs are included to ensure that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.